# HTML5 Canvas line points from database

Tags: c#, html, canvas

we are c# asp.net writing an app that saves positions of items in a database. I would like to use the data (x,y, hight,width) to draw a representation of the object on screen using the HTML5 canvas element.

I can draw objects ok using static values put into the web page, but i want to load the points of a line from the database. What's the best way to query the database for the information, and load it into the javascript on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Load point from database using [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), then draw lines using [jCanvas](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/), [CanvasQuery](http://canvasquery.com/) or any other similar libraries.

Comment: @beakersoft. Yes, use AJAX.  Sounds like you're up to speed on canvas drawing commands, so just get the ajax response and issue drawing commands--no need for a 3rd party library.